# Google Sheets cell format is inconsistent when querying between sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a query to pull data from a "sub-sheet" to my "master sheet". Both ranges are formatted to be accounting, however when the data is populated into the master sheet, the number formatting is wonky and there isn't enough space between the dollar sign and the value.

[Both rows are using near-identical Queries, with the same formatting selected but the outputs look completely different.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SygL9.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share a copy of your sheet, and do not rely on images as these may be unaccessible to some users...

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
1 - Setup all the rows from the undesired sources as plain text.
2 - Delete the problematic rows in the source sheet "sub-sheet" and undo.

This should do it.
Include the source appearance if not.
and one more thing go to format>Number>Costum number format
and take a sceenshot for both sources and master sheet or include your sheets in a folder.